# Adding Google Service Account Credentials by a groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, google-api

I want to add Google Service Account credentials using a groovy file initializer on `init.groovy.d`. So far I could define UserName-Password credentials and `String` credentials. However, the Google API key requires a special credential type: `GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials`. I could not manage to add that type of credential.

How can I define Google Service Account credentials of type `GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials` through a groovy script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an answer on that link: https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-oauth-plugin/issues/5

I have changed that slightly, as that answer did not work on the latest Jenkins installation:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsStore
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain
import com.google.jenkins.plugins.credentials.oauth.GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials
import com.google.jenkins.plugins.credentials.oauth.JsonServiceAccountConfig
import hudson.model.FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem

def jsonFile = new File("/myfilepath/key.json")
def fileItem = new FileItemImpl(jsonFile)

def config = new JsonServiceAccountConfig()
config.setJsonKeyFileUpload(fileItem)

Credentials credentials = new GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials("gpc", config, null)

SystemCredentialsProvider instance = SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance()
CredentialsStore store = instance.getStore()
store.addCredentials(Domain.global(), credentials)
```